# how to get tcp connection candidate from twilio stun/turn server?

Tags: tcp, webrtc, twilio, nat, turn

i am using a twilio free account and generated twilio turn servers and credentials. With these as ICEServerOptions, I am getting candidate which has only UDP connections, but I needed a TCP connection for reliable data transfer using webRTC.

Is there any way to get TCP relay/srflx connection from the twilio stun/turn servers?
If yes then please let me know how?

Thanks
MJ

Comment: I just generated an [NAT Access Token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/token) and had two TCP candidates. Can you share the code you are using to generate it?

Comment: my command:
Maheshs-MacBook-Air:~ maheshjena$ curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC5ebd66f6153d2bbb8bb8f8b794c95765/Tokens.json \
>     -u "AC5ebd66f6153d2bbb8bb8f8b794c95765:[MY_AUTH_TOKEN_*****]"

Comment: after this command i get my turn server link, username and credentials. when I use it as ICE Server options, and get the candidates, there are no TCP candidates for srflx or relay, i can found only UDP candidates.

Comment: UDP is the preferred transport for WebRTC. If you specifically want only  TCP candidates then you might need to adjust the iceServers response to remove the UDP options.

Comment: actually my original question was, the twilio ice servers are not giving any TCP candidates for srflx and relay options. I am getting 2 TCP candidate as you said but they are for host not for srflx or relay.
I also tried removing all the UDP candidates and using those 2 tcp host candidate in offer and answer but SetRemoteDescription() failed with those candidates. 
I know to support TCP relay connection the TURN server need to support port 80 and 443 in it.
Is there anyway to get the TCP candidate for srflx/relay connection from twilio server?

Comment: WebRTC does not support TCP allocations as described in RFC 6062.

Comment: i studied [RFC 6062] (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6062#page-10) but unfortunately could not find anything which say we cannot use TCP for webRTC. actually i wanted to use webRTC for file transfer and i feel TCP is more reliable than UDP for this purpose.
Plz let me know if you have any other solution for this!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, Twilio by default doesn't add TURN/TCP to their configuration of Twilio Client, although they might do so in the future.

For now, you'll need to explicitly add that in, using something like the call below:

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token, { 
"iceServers": [ { "url": "turn:global.turn.twilio.com:443?transport=tcp" } ] 
});
```

That said, you should note the following:

1. WebRTC doesn't run on a reliable connection for audio and video transmission. If what you are aiming for is real time media, then UDP is your best friend. TCP is used only as a necessary evil when firewalls block UDP
2. Once WebRTC is able to connect its ICE candidates via UDP, it will simply stop trying and in most cases, you won't see TCP candidates connecting at all - they get lower priority because of (1)

Comment: thanks for the answer, @Tsahi.
Actually i want to use webRTC for file transfer, thats why i wanted TCP candidates for this.
I have already tried the way, you suggested but it still does not give tcp candidates for srflx or relay. 
Have you tried in any different way to get the tcp candidates from twilio servers?

Comment: For file transfer, use WebRTC's data channel. That runs over SCTP, which you can configure to be reliable. See here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/ and here https://bloggeek.me/sctp-data-channel/ for more information

Comment: thanks @Tsahi, I will definitely check that.
hv a great day.